# "stash apply" in git override changes got from a pull

Tags: git, git-stash

I got in this situation today. I had some changes in one file to commit but before I wanted to do a pull for this file so I did the next

1. Stash changes from my working directory
2. Pulling changes bringing changes in this same file from other person
3. Stash apply my changes

What I have found after "stash apply" is that the changes I got after doing the pull were overriden with with my stash changes.

1. Is this normal? There shouldnt be merge conflicts when applying my stash changes affect the changes in the same file got from the pull?
2. How to deal with this situation in order to avoid my stash changes override 
   changes got from a pull?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the exact commands you used? I would not expect the use of `git stash apply` to trump the upstream changes, but instead to conflict and expect you to resolve them.

Comment: 1) git stash -m "whatever"                                                                                            2) git pull                                                                                                                      3) git stash apply

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stash your local changes first, then pull, then pop the stash.

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

You will have to manually resolve anything that overrides changes from remote, because it will have conflicts.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, thats what I did. But the point is that I think with git stash doesnt show any conflicts because you are not applying changes in some branch but in your working directory so git doesnt have control about the changes that were made in your working directory, Right?